# How to use FMOD with C++?

Tags: c++, g++, fmod

I'm trying to create a simple mp3 player using FMOD:

```
#include "inc/fmod.h"

int main() 
{
    FSOUND_Init(44100, 32, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile the program I get the following error:

```
holle@x300:justmp3$ pwd
/media/daten/Entwicklung/C/justmp3
holle@x300:justmp3$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)/lib
holle@x300:justmp3$ ls $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
libfmodex-4.34.02.so  libfmodexL-4.34.02.so
holle@x300:justmp3$ g++ -o mp3 mp3.cpp
mp3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
mp3.cpp:8: error: ‘FSOUND_Init’ was not declared in this scope
```

What's my mistake? How could I get g++ to compile the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FSOUND_Init is an FMOD 3 API function, you are using FMOD Ex so that function doesn't exist. To initialize FMOD Ex you should include "fmod.hpp" and use the functions:

System_Create to create the FMOD system object, then

System::init to initialize, followed by

System::createStream to load your MP3, then

System::playSound to play it.

There are a bunch of useful examples that ship with FMOD that you could use as a reference, especially the playstream example for what you want to achieve. Also there is full documentation in CHM format. If you are porting code from FMOD 3 I would recommend reading the migration guide in the fmodex.chm docs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the headers for the library too, add

```
#include <fmod.h>
```

at the beginning of your code.

Answer (score -2):

You must go to the FMOD page (https://fmod.com/), and log in to download the version for custom graphics engines.

[image]

Once installed, we go to the folder where we saved the file to look for the lib folder, which is inside the FMOD Studio API/Windows/api/core folder. Then we choose the folder that corresponds to the platform we are working with and copy the .dll files to our project.

[image]

We also copy the libraries (.lib files) to our libraries (.lib) folder.

[image]

Then we look for the lib folder, which is inside the FMOD Studio API folder
Windows/api/studio.

[image]

We choose the folder that corresponds to the system we work with.
We copy the libraries (.lib files) to our libraries folder (.lib).

[image]

Then we go to the inc folder that is inside the FMOD Studio folder
API/Windows/apistudio and copy the files to it.
We return to the includes folder of our project and create the FMOD folder,
where we put the copied files.

[image]

Likewise, we go to the inc folder that is inside the FMOD Studio folder
Windows\api\studio API to copy your files. Returning to our project, Inside the include folder of our project we create the FMOD folder,
where we put the copied files.

[image]

With the above we can now use the FMOD library in our project. Now in the main file we add the fmod_studio.hpp libraries
and fmod.hpp.

```
#include <FMOD/fmod_studio.hpp>
#include <FMOD/fmod.hpp>
```

Initialize an instance of the FMOD engine.

```
FMOD::System* system;
FMOD_RESULT result=FMOD::System_Create(&system)
```

If the sound is 3D I establish the speed of sound, distance unit and scaling factor of the
ambient sound.

```
system->set3DSettings(1.0,1.0f,1.0f);
```

I initialize and prepare FMOD for audio playback.

```
result=system->init(512,FMOD_INIT_NORMAL,nullptr);
```

Load sound into memory for streaming or setup

```
callback based sounds
FMOD::Sound* sound;
result=system->createSound("name.mp3",FMOD_DEFAULT,nullptr,&sound);
```

I create a channel to play the sound.

```
FMOD::Channel*channel;
result=system->playSound(sound,nullptr,false,&channel)
```

That would be all, don't forget to release the sound engine, channels and delete the songs you loaded.

```
system->release();
channel->stop();
```